# Two radio buttons share one “id”conditionally?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to adopt different design for a page on mobile and desktop.
And for this, 3 blocks of radio button and some other stuff needs to be redesigned for mobile interface but on  **Same Page**.

So, my concern is that can 2 blocks share one ID as i am hiding and showing as per media queries.

Example:

**Block 1**

```
<div class="visible-xs">
   <input type="radio" name="yellow" id="yellow-color" value="14" 
   class="yellow radio-custom" checked="checked" />
   <input type="radio" name="red" id="red-color" value="52" 
   class="red radio-custom" />
</div>
```

**Block 2**

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
   <input type="radio" name="yellow" id="yellow-color" value="14" 
   class="yellow radio-custom1" checked="checked" />
   <input type="radio" name="red" id="red-color" value="52" 
   class="red radio-custom1" />
</div>
```

It is working in terms of functionality but problem is that radio at mobile page is not getting checked

Comment: That does not follow the 23c standards.. Sorry.. But you shouldn't be doing that

Comment: ID's are unique identifier, it's either hide one of them if not selected

Comment: should i redirect to one new page for mobile?

Comment: IDs are unique, you should not repeat them. But `name` and `class` are not, so you could probably use `name` for your needs. Anyway, forms use `name` for transmitting data...

Comment: but, it is not getting checked on mobile by default..

Comment: But redirecting to new page on mobile will cause difficulties while SEO .. m i right?

Comment: Ok, another hint: `checked` will work if only **one element** of a group with the **same name** has `checked="checked"`. So, if you have two elements with a `yellow` name, only **one** has to have the `checked="checked"` attribute. In your example, both `yellow` name elements have that attribute.

Comment: @Gags I'm glad I helped, good luck!

Comment: @AlejandroIván .. do i need to worry of standards here for such a thing??

Comment: @Gags no, that method is the standard way. You can't repeat `id`, but `name` is another story. That's the way to deal with radio buttons.

Comment: But i am repeating ID here....

Comment: @Gags then you should change that. When submitting the form, the server receives the value using the `name` attribute, not the `id` (`id` is, in fact, ignored). I'm pretty sure you don't even need to deal with `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To group radio inputs they have to use the same `name` attribute and to check one of them automatically, only **one** radio input of that **same-name-group** has to have the `checked="checked"` attribute.

If two or more have that attribute, none will be selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer your question with another question. :)

Why dont you uses only one form and format, based weather is desktop or mobile, using CSS?

this way you wouldnt have to create 2 forms.

I am thinking about something like this:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/targeting-specific-devices-in-your-style-sheets.html

This page I sent have basic instruction. The idea is to identify the device and deliver the proper CSS, this way you only need one DIV and the 2 CSS.

you could also do that with javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1)) {
        document.write("css_mobile.css");
    } 
    else
    {
        document.write("css_browser.css");
    }
// ]]>
</script>
```

cheers

Comment: no man.. because only 3-4 blocks needs to be rendered on mobile not whole page

Comment: Please add a code example to the answer instead of just linking to an offsite one as links may not work in the future.

Comment: This is called responsive web design

Comment: I know it is responsive design.. but how this will help in my case.. as position and other things are also changed